# How do I propagate relative uncertainty through atan2?

Tags: numerical-methods, error-propagation

I've got $y = \sin(\theta)$ and $x = \cos(\theta)$ with some relative error on both.  If I compute $\theta$ with $\theta = \operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$, how do I propagate the relative error from the inputs to a relative error on the angle?

Comment: You know the propagation of error formula? $\delta f^2 = \sum_i (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\delta x_i)^2 $

Comment: I don't, total newbie here.  Would that work for relative error?

Comment: By relative error you mean $\frac{\delta x}{x}$ right?. In the formula you are supposed to use the absolute error. But I guess if you are actually doing an experiment you have the values of $x,y$ right?. you might want to take a look at (particularly the non-linear part) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty

Comment: It's not quite an experiment, it's a numerical calculation to get x and y.  I can find an equation for the relative error bounds on them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping from polar to Cartesian is

$$\binom xy = \binom{r\cos \theta}{r\sin \theta}$$

with total differential

$$
\binom{dx}{dy}
=\binom{\cos\theta\,dr-r\sin\theta\,d\theta}{\sin\theta\,dr+r\cos\theta\,d\theta} 
=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}}_{\textstyle=:M} \binom{dr}{d \theta}
$$
The matrix $M$ encodes how small changes in $r$ and $\theta$ translate to small changes in $x$ and $y$.

If you are mapping the other way, then

$$\binom{dr}{d \theta} = M^{-1}\binom{dx}{dy}$$

So all you have to do is to invert $M$ because using $\operatorname{atan2}(y,x)$ just gives you the $\theta$-coordinate for cartesian $(x,y)$.  Notice that this just gives you the ideal error propagation and does not care for gory detail of your atan2 implementation.

More spacifically,

$$M^{-1} = \frac 1{|M|}\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\theta & r\sin\theta \\
-\sin\theta & \cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
-\dfrac1r\sin\theta & \dfrac1r\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

so that
$$d\theta = \frac1r (-\sin\theta ~~ \cos\theta)
\binom{dx}{dy}
$$

Maybe you find it more useful to express the derivative in terms of $x$ and $y$.  In that case:

$$d\theta = \frac1{x^2+y^2} (-ydx +xdy)$$

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Derivative) for example. Thus for $\delta\theta$:

$$\delta\theta^2 = \frac1{(x^2+y^2)^2}(y^2\delta x^2 + x^2\delta y^2)$$

In the case where $\delta x_r=\delta x/x$ denotes the relative error:

$$\delta\theta^2 = \frac{x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}(\delta x_r^2 + \delta y_r^2)$$

Comment: If I replace dx/dy by dx/x and dy/y for relative error, would this still work?

Comment: I used x*dx to get absolute error and I think this works for me, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that should work. I also added a formula that uses $x$ and $y$ directly, so you can express the error in terms of them.